# different output in Nested list Comprehension and equivalent for loop

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I am learning list comprehension and I am not able to understand, why the outputs are different in case of list comprehension and equivalent for loop.

List Comprehension:

```
>>> [b for b in range(0,a) for a in range(1,5)]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

equivalent for loop:

```
>>> list = []
>>> for a in range(1,5):
...     for b in range(0,a):
...         list.append(b)
...
>>> list
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Please help me to understand why are they giving different output and what is correct way to read the list comprehension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*First* expression yields error unless you executed *second* code first:

```
>>> [b for b in range(0,a) for a in range(1,5)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

You can get your result if `a` equals 4, that is if you execute your second statement first:

```
>>> list = []
>>> for a in range(1,5):
...     for b in range(0,a):
...         list.append(b)
...
>>> list
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> a
4
>>> [b for b in range(0,a) for a in range(1,5)]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Correct expression would be

```
>>> [b for a in range(1,5) for b in range(0, a)]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to reverse the order of your "chained" for-loops:

```
[b for a in range(1,5) for b in range(0,a)]
```

(I have to admit I have found this ordering counter-intuitive at first too...)

In general, this:

```
[ EXP for VAR1 in SEQ1 for VAR2 in SEQ2 ]
```

translates to this:

```
for VAR1 in SEQ1:
  for VAR2 in SEQ2:
     ...
```

So when you do `[b for b in range(0,a) for a in range(1,5)]`, the value `a` previously had is used when `range(0,a)` is evaluated. (and an error is raised if `a` was previously undefined.)

Comment: Yep.  List comp `for` loop order == ordinary `for` loop order.